# create charts in excel using (python,perl)(linux)

Tags: c++, python, perl, python-2.7

I need to generate chart/graph into Excel sheet from data present into Excel sheet. I am using python in linux environment. I have gone through below question but did not find any answer.I am using python 2.7 in linux enviroment. I am flexible to use perl also if we have any solution.

[use python to generate graph in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568319/use-python-to-generate-graph-in-excel)

[How to generate Excel spreadsheets with embedded graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462025/how-to-generate-excel-spreadsheets-with-embedded-graphs)

(Tried with openpyxl :[Graphs in xlsx File overwrite by openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905610/graphs-in-xlsx-file-overwrite-by-openpyxl))

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to create graph from Excel sheet data in Excel using python or perl

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly didn't work? -- This is a Q&A site (as in "why does this function x() not return the expected value"), not a "solve my programming assignment for me" site (as in "I need this done, please post code").

Comment: Ya I have tried with openpyxl and found that xlwt and openpyxl both do not support the graph creation

Answer (score 2):

I have found below url which may be useful .

https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart#NAME

Comment: I wrote that module and I am currently porting it (via Excel::Writer::XLSX) to a Python module called [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/). Charts aren't supported yet but the [work on them is about to start](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/excel_writer_xlsx.html). Check back in about a month.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for reply.But I need to implement within 2 to 3 days.Please update us if you done with this module

Comment: If you need something that works now then look at the Perl module [Excel::Writer:XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Chart.pm) Charts. They are more advanced than Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

Answer (score 1):

The Python module XlsxWriter [supports charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart_examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from your other question...

[Here](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/charts.html) is the documentation on how to create a chart in openpyxl

The example is a little broken, compare to this instead.

```
values = Reference(ws, (1, 1), (1, 95))
series = Series(values, title="Sample" )
chart = LineChart()
chart.append(series)
ws.add_chart(chart)
```